# Override Bootstrap table border-collapse style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, css-specificity, border-spacing

Bootstrap has a `table {border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing:0;}` style.  I want to override this so I've create a class and applied it to the table in question:

```
table.FormGroupContainer
{
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
}
```

but *still* the borders remain collapsed.  The Chrome element inspector shows the Bootstrap CSS has been overridden but only disabling the style in the inspector allows a border spacing.  I have observed this in IE 11 and Firefox 31.0.  Inline styles also appear to override (as shown in Chrome inspector) but have no effect until I disable the Bootstrap style.

CSS load order also seems to make no difference.  *What gives?* Isn't the class higher specificity?

Comment: Normalize.css (part of Bootstrap 3) adds the collapse.  CSS load order always makes a difference. If the style is applied to the table it will work provided that it's after Bootstrap css and no other css is conflicting with it: http://jsbin.com/bavogi/1/edit

Comment: @Christina Ok, say Bootstrap's CSS is loaded last.  Doesn't the higher specificity of `table.FormGroupContainer` on: `<table class="FormGroupContainer"></table>` allow the FormGroupContainer to override the Bootstrap table CSS?

Comment: Yes, if that's all there is. Remember this is normalize.css which is part of Bootstrap but maintained separately.

Comment: @Christina I notice that the Bootstrap class has `media=screen` does this change the specificity?  I'm using the compiled Bootstrap theme so I can't remove the Normalize.css (I have 2 monolithic Bootstrap bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap-theme.min.css files).

Comment: BTW how do I mark your comment as a helpful answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load order was an issue here.  My stylesheet was being loaded *before* Bootstrap.  I added greater specificity to the rule in my stylesheet that allowed it to compete with Bootstrap's `table` CSS.  Thanks @Christina.